# Hibernate named query parameter

Tags: hibernate, named

I am having problem with named query parameter. My query is as follow:

```
<sql-query name="getCustomer">
<![CDATA[
     select * from customer where customerId=:custId and billId in ( :billIdList )
]]>
</sql-query>
```

I am setting all parameters, but having problem in :billIdList whenever I am setting this parameter I am getting a Empty list of customers. My :billIdList is in the string form e.g: 5,6,7,9. There is data in DB also with above values. It works fine when I am writing query 
in program it self.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parameters with more than one value you need to use a `setParameterList()` method of Hibernate's `Query` interface:

```
query.setParameterList("billIdList", new int[] {5,6,7,9});
```